# Decision tree doesn't quite work, is there a better alternative?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a problem that I have been trying to use decision trees to solve. There is a data set of pricing information for products sold by a company. The goal is to infer the pricing algorithm for each product based on the product's name, type, and characteristics. However, the data is incomplete and may contain a few inaccuracies due to manual data entry.  Products can be priced using several possible algorithms:

1. Price is a fixed dollar amount (widget costs $20)
2. Price is a percentage of MSRP (widget costs X% of MSRP, note X could vary by product classes)
3. Price is based on a cost per piece (package of widgets costs $2 per piece)

Using decision trees, I have been able to identify the products priced using algorithm #1, but have struggled to make progress on algorithm #2 and #3. Since price is a continuous variable, the leaf nodes always represent the average of the target variable. But this doesn't seem to work for #2 and #3, since these would be a function of other variables, not the dependent variable.

Is there a clever way to implement this using decisions trees? Any recommended alternate techniques that could identify the pricing algorithms used? Note, I am not interested in predictions, but rather explain the pricing rules/algorithm that fit the existing data.

I am using SAS Enterprise Miner, but may have access to other tools as well.

Comment: Are you actually sure that you have identified 1) seeing as products could cost $20 even if priced according to mechanisms 2/3. Seeing this I doubt how you could find this out definitively without knowing X and widget cost for each product. I think this is a lack of data problem not one of algorithm choice/application.